# Why Logic App designer in VS 2019 gives Object reference not set to an instance of an object when trying to login to Azure?

Tags: visual-studio, azure-logic-apps

Steps:
-I open VS 2009 (logic app tools installed)
-New Logic App project
-Open LogicApp.json with Logic Apps Designer
-Login and selecting resource group

ERROR:
"Object reference not set to an instance of an object"

This happens in tenant A, but not in tenant B.
I do have contributors rights in tenant A. I have co-owner in tenant B.